# How to retrieve data from google speech async

Tags: google-speech-api, get-request

I'm setting up a server, and I need to use the Google speech API in order to translate an audio to a text.
This server send a post request to Google's API and retrieve the NAME(ID) of the operation. Then I'm trying to make a get request with tihs NAME(ID) to retrieve the data, but I'm getting a 404 error.

I've already tryied to use api.get('/v1p1beta1/operations/{NAME}') with my API KEY from Google like this api.get('/v1p1beta1/operations/{NAME}?key={key}') but then I got a bad request.
Also this code worked, but stopped and I don't know why.

```js
 const api = await axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://speech.googleapis.com',
    crossDomain: true,
    responseType: 'json',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': "Bearer <<TOKEN>>"
    },
    });
    // calling api
    api.get('/v1p1beta1/operations/{NAME}')
    .then(resp=>{
        console.log( resp);

    }).
    catch('error');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem, it was when I return the NAME(ID) from the server, It was rounded and then when I called the GET function the ID didn't match. What I did was stringfy the value, and it solved the problem.

```js
return JSON.stringify(result.data.name);
```